# Next.js - How to get the reaction in getServerSideProps using fetch get query on client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a getServerSideProps call on the directory page.

pages/catalog/index.js

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  const response = await fetch(
    `http://someDomen.com/api/ipro/catalog?${ctx?.query?.page ? `page=${ctx.query.page}` : 'page=1'}`,
  )
  const data = await response.json()

  return {
    props: {
      data: data?.data,
    },
  }
}
```

Is it possible to make a get query with parameters on the client to the catalog page so that getServerSideProps responds to this query and gives a new response each time?

Example of a request on a client:
fetch('http://localhost:3000/catalog?page=5')

It is necessary that the getServerSideProps responds to the get request from the client and the url on the client's side is unchanged and equals http ://localhost: 3000/catalog

Comment: are you asking for an opinion?

Comment: If you want `getServerSideProps` to run again you'll have to trigger a page navigation with `router.push()`.

Comment: @juliomalves - Thank you for the answer, there are ways not to change the client url and run getServerSireProps?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking whether you can pass the entire query string to your getServerSideProps.

You can create a function like this

```js
    serialize = function(obj) {
      var str = [];
      for (var p in obj)
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
          str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        }
      return str.join("&");
    }
    
    const props = { page: 1, category: 'abc' }
    
    console.log(serialize(props))
```

and then in your getServerSideProps

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {

  query.page = query.page ? query.page : 1 //you can modify it too before serializing 

  const response = await fetch(
    `http://someDomen.com/api/ipro/?${serialize(query)}`,
  )

  const data = await response.json()

  return {
    props: {
      data: data?.data,
    },
  }
}
```

client side: http://localhost/catalog?page=123&catalog=abc

Comment: The question is not how to betray the parameters and it is convenient to use them. To make a get request from the client with the transfer of parameters and so that the getServerSideProps responds to this request and gives new data through props.

Comment: router.push(`${router.asPath}/?search=abc`) <=== this? Your question is hard to understand